# Fetch request is running on npm run web but gives error on phone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

```
//I face big complications here, my app doesn't start up and I get this strange error I haven't faced before. I'm running my app via Expo, just as a sidenote.
```

const onSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

```
console.log(fullname1, email1, password1, address1, phone1);

let fullname, email, password, address, phone;

fullname = fullname1;
email = email1;
password = password1;
address = address1;
phone = phone1;
//check for empty input fields
    if (
      fullname == null ||
      email == null ||
      password == null ||
      address == null ||
      phone == null
    ) {
      window.alert("empty input fields");
    } else {
      await fetch("localhost:9000/customer-registration", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          fullname,
          email,
          password,
          address,
          phone,
        }),
      })
        .then((res) => {
          res.json().then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.empty === "true") {
              alert("Empty input fields");
            } else if (data.flag === "true") {
              window.alert("Email already exist");
            } else {
              window.alert("Customer Resgistered successfully");
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          window.alert("Registration failed");
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: *"I get this strange error"* what error there isn't any in your question? Furthermore please format your code. This is unreadable. Take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info

Comment: try ending your url with / like so: ```localhost:9000/customer-registration/```

Answer (score 0):

"Network request failed" issue when call api usually comes when.

1. The request format doesn't match with the api.
2. The api url doesn't exist.

First you can check if the api url exists with Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy to check what request are going out and what responses are coming, like Fiddler or Charles, probably the request is malformed.